# With Symfony2 migrations changes in nullable parameter is not considered

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I am using migrations in Symonfy2 (2.3).
When I change a field in any of my entities from :

```
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
```

to

```
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
```

And run

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

Then no change is detected.

Is this expected behavior? If yes, How should I do to update my databases (dev, test, staging and prod) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons, my nullable parameter was on antoher line instead of being on the same line as other parameters :

I had this:

```
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="persofixe", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/^[0]{1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8}$/",
 *     message="Le téléphone doit commencer par 0 et contenir 10 chiffres (sans espace ni point).")
 */
private $persoFixe;
```

Instead of this:

```
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="persofixe", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/^[0]{1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8}$/",
 *     message="Le téléphone doit commencer par 0 et contenir 10 chiffres (sans espace ni point).")
 */
private $persoFixe;
```

Now everything is working as expected. I hope nobody will have lost time on this... :(